# NumPy: how implement Mathematica's MixedRadix in NumPy?

Tags: python, numpy, wolfram-mathematica

Mathematica has a built-in function [MixedRadix](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MixedRadix.html) which maps an integer to a list of digits in a mixed radix numerical system.

Here's my Python version of the same:

```
def mixed_radix(num, bases):
    digits = []
    for base in bases[::-1]:
        num, digit = divmod(num, base)
        digits.append(digit)
    return digits[::-1]
```

Is there an idiomatic/built-in way of doing this in NumPy?

Answer (score 1):

I discovered the answer by chance:

```
>>> np.unravel_index(571, (12, 9, 6))
(10, 5, 1)
```

and the reverse direction:

```
>>> np.ravel_multi_index((10, 5, 1), (12, 9, 6))
571
```